# Write Python Dict to InfluxDB?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I've been playing around trying to figure out how to write a python dict into InfluxDB with no luck.  I've tried using the InfluxDBClient as well as just using a Requests Post via API.

I have the following code:

```
for server in  data['service_group_stat']['member_stat_list']:
    metrics = {}
    metrics['measurement'] = "LB01"
    metrics['tags'] = {}
    metrics['fields'] = {}
    metrics['tags']['SGNAME'] = name
    metrics['tags']['SRVNAME'] = server['server']
    metrics['fields']['CURCONNS'] = server['cur_conns']
    metrics['fields']['TOTCONNS'] = server['tot_conns']
    metrics['fields']['REQBYTES'] = server['req_bytes']
    metrics['fields']['REQPKTS'] = server['req_pkts']
    metrics['fields']['RESPBYTES'] = server['resp_bytes']
    metrics['fields']['RESPPKTS'] = server['resp_pkts']
    pprint(metrics)
```

Which will give me the following output:

```
{'fields': {'CURCONNS': 33,
            'REQBYTES': 3151292236,
            'REQPKTS': 21160834,
            'RESPBYTES': 66671993850,
            'RESPPKTS': 51709706,
            'TOTCONNS': 332177},
 'measurement': 'LB01',
 'tags': {'SGNAME': 'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443',
          'SRVNAME': u'WWW0006'}}
{'fields': {'CURCONNS': 39,
            'REQBYTES': 3387948728,
            'REQPKTS': 23103920,
            'RESPBYTES': 71703285665,
            'RESPPKTS': 55687510,
            'TOTCONNS': 369628},
 'measurement': 'LB01',
 'tags': {'SGNAME': 'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443',
          'SRVNAME': u'WWW0005'}}
{'fields': {'CURCONNS': 16,
            'REQBYTES': 3401134891,
            'REQPKTS': 24014042,
            'RESPBYTES': 70917802336,
            'RESPPKTS': 55029480,
            'TOTCONNS': 342360},
 'measurement': 'LB01',
 'tags': {'SGNAME': 'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443',
          'SRVNAME': u'WWW0004'}}
```

I've tried just using a requests.post to leverage the InfluxDB API:

```
url = "http://localhost:8086/write?db=metrics"

r = requests.post(url, metrics)
```

However I seem to always get a 400 response:

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
```

I've also tried using the InfluxDBClient:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

# Define InfluxDB Client Information

client = InfluxDBClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=8086, username='root', password='root', database='metrics')

for server in  data['service_group_stat']['member_stat_list']:
    metrics = {}
    metrics['measurement'] = "LB01"
    metrics['tags'] = {}
    metrics['fields'] = {}
    metrics['tags']['SGNAME'] = name
    metrics['tags']['SRVNAME'] = server['server']
    metrics['fields']['CURCONNS'] = server['cur_conns']
    metrics['fields']['TOTCONNS'] = server['tot_conns']
    metrics['fields']['REQBYTES'] = server['req_bytes']
    metrics['fields']['REQPKTS'] = server['req_pkts']
    metrics['fields']['RESPBYTES'] = server['resp_bytes']
    metrics['fields']['RESPPKTS'] = server['resp_pkts']

client.write_points(metrics)
```

Which ends up giving me the following error:

```
    client.write_points(metrics)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 456, in write_points
    tags=tags, protocol=protocol)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 506, in _write_points
    protocol=protocol
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 292, in write
    data = make_lines(data, precision).encode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/line_protocol.py", line 126, in make_lines
    point.get('measurement', data.get('measurement'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any advice on what what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass a list of dicts to InfluxDBClient.write_points() when using the json protocol (which is default).
You can check [the source code](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/blob/master/influxdb/line_protocol.py#L121/) of the make_lines() method to be convinced that it iterates over points.

Answer : use `client.write_points([metrics])`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last week on my internship's project. It seems that python does not like the syntax like :

`metrics['tags']['SGNAME'] = name`

Maybe you can try something like this.. It worked for me.

```
for server in  data['service_group_stat']['member_stat_list']:
    metrics = {}
    metrics['measurement'] = "LB01"
    tags = {}
    fields = {}
    tags['SGNAME'] = name
    tags['SRVNAME'] = server['server']
    metrics['tags'] = tags
    fields['CURCONNS'] = server['cur_conns']
    fields['TOTCONNS'] = server['tot_conns']
    fields['REQBYTES'] = server['req_bytes']
    fields['REQPKTS'] = server['req_pkts']
    fields['RESPBYTES'] = server['resp_bytes']
    fields['RESPPKTS'] = server['resp_pkts']
    metrics['fields'] = fields
client.write_points(metrics)
```

Hope it helped